# Which one of these clips would track the best?

Tags: tracking

So I recorded some clips at my school. They are all in my [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BzgDIjhDOu6EMUYtc1NCc1JNLTg&usp=sharing).

I'm pretty new to tracking in Blender; I have used Adobe AfterEffect's wonderful 3D Camera Tracker in the past. I would like to ask the experienced trackers on this website which of the above linked clips looks like they would track the best. I'm trying to recreate [this effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=igXf5WK49Yw) as a final product.

Comment: This will be a great question to have on the site, if we can get a good, thorough answer with generic application.

Comment: Just choose one that meets the criteria outlined on this post: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/motion-tracking-my-model-zooms-in-or-out-or-is-sliding

Comment: @JoshSilveus There are a few rules to keep the site organized: **One question per post**. Different questions should be asked in different posts. Questions asking for opinions do not fit the question and answer format used here. Please take a few minutes and read the [help] section and this link: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/asking

Comment: I disagree that he's asking for an opinion. It sounds like he's asking for guidance on how to identify a suitable candidate for tracking. But yeah, one question per post.

Comment: cegaton has it http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42329/how-can-i-get-better-results-when-doing-camera-motion-tracking

Comment: How do I accept a comment as an answer? I'll delete this comment afterwards, I'm just not sure. @cegaton

Comment: @JoshSilveous comments are not answers... so they cannot be voted. If you found a solution feel free to write your own answer. Read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer